# Can I use a single resistor for multiple LED with different +ve sources?

Tags: led, resistors

In the photo below I would like to use a single resistor after the LEDs, instead of having individual resistors before the LEDs. Is this problematic? Will it work?

[image]

Comment: No, there are tolerances inbetween one LED and another. The LED with the lowest Vf will carry a lot more current then the others.

Comment: **Looks like Diode OR logic ;)**  but problematic due to sharing current and voltage drop.

Comment: How are the LEDs driven? What is controlling the terminals D3, D4 and D5?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you shouldn't be connecting LEDs in parallel even if they are of the same type.  This question has been asked a good number of times: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/130522/7036), [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/22291/7036), [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/174584/7036).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that safely *if*:

- Only one LED is on at a time.
- The voltage of the circuit is less than the maximum reverse voltage of the LEDs. This often isn't specified by 5 V is generally quite safe.

Otherwise switching two or more on at a time connects them in parallel. In this situation the one with the lowest forward voltage will pass the most current. If they are different colour LEDs then the one with the lowest forward voltage, V<sub>f</sub>, will be quite bright and the others relatively dim.

[image]

*Figure 1. Variations in V<sub>f</sub> with different colours of LEDs. Source: [LED I-V curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

[image]

*Figure 2. Variations in V<sub>f</sub> for the same type of LED due to variations in manufacture. Source: [Variations in V<sub>f</sub> and binning](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/variations-vf-binning/).*

---

As you reminded me in the comments, I forgot to cover the current sharing aspect. The voltage at the top of R1 will be reasonably constant (because the voltage drop across the LEDs would be reasonably similar) so the current through R1 will be constant if one or more LEDs is on. That means that the current will be shared between the LEDs - fairly evenly if they're all the same colour but not so evenly if not.

Comment: So if switching 2 on at once is connecting them in parallel, this would mean the current drop would roughly double? And the resistor if limiting to 15ma would be shared between the 2 LED and would only see 7.5ma (roughly)?

Comment: Correct, and I completely forgot to cover that in the answer. I'll add it in.

Comment: OK. Will mark as answer. THanks for the detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

It's problematic because nothing is ever identical so the LED with the lowest voltage drop will cause all the current to flow through it while the other two LEDs never turn on because the voltage drop across them isn't high enough.

Comment: even though they have different +ve signal source?

Comment: As the others have pointed out above, it's okay if you only ever turn on one at a time. You'll run into trouble if you try to turn on more than one at a time.